# Как составить алгоритм для поиска комбинаций в массивах?

Tags: алгоритм, комбинаторика, php

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста придумать алгоритм для поиска всех возможных групп из комбинаций.

Исходные данные:

**Массив комбинаций**

```
$combinations => [
a => [11, 38],
b => [38, 64, 71],
c => [11, 24, 38, 65]
d => [128, 38, 57, 40]
...    
]
```

каждая комбинация в этом массиве может состоять из 2, 3 или 4 чисел

Нужно найти все возможные группы из 4х чисел, в которых будут участвовать от 2-х до 4-х комбинаций из массива комбинаций и определить сколько комбинаций входит в группу и каких. В группе должно быть 4 числа, ни больше, ни меньше. Например можно составить группу в которой будут участвовать 2 комбинации (a и b):

```
$group => [11, 38, 64, 71]
```

В эту группу входит первая и вторая комбинация.
Третья комбинация (с) уже содержит в себе первую комбинацию (a), т.е. она тоже состоит из двух комбинаций.

Как найти группы, в которых будет от 2х до 4х комбинаций?
Я нагородил много вложенных циклов и то, работает криво и ищет только среди комбинаций которые состоят из 2х чисел. Код получился огромный и страшный, что даже боюсь показывать его кому-то. А страшный он из-за того, что не могу придумать оптимальный алгоритм поиска групп.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код:

```
# Входящий массив:
$ar = array(
    'a' =>  '11, 38',
    'b' =>  '38, 64, 71',
    'c' =>  '11, 24, 38, 65',
    'd' =>  '128, 38, 57, 40'
);

# Искомые числа:
$in = array('11', '38', '64', '71');

$result = array();

foreach($ar as $key => $value){
    $line = explode(',',$value);

    foreach($in as $inn){
        if(in_array($inn,$line)){
            $result[$key]['count']++;
        $result[$key][] = $inn;
        }
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Результат работы кода:

```
    Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [count] => 2
            [0] => 11
            [1] => 38
        )

    [b] => Array
        (
            [count] => 3
            [0] => 38
            [1] => 64
            [2] => 71
        )

    [c] => Array
        (
            [count] => 2
            [0] => 11
            [1] => 38
        )

    [d] => Array
        (
            [count] => 1
            [0] => 38
        )

)
```

Надеюсь, что помог.

UPD:

```
$ar = array(
    'a' =>  '11,38',
    'b' =>  '38,64,71',
    'c' =>  '11,24,38,65',
    'd' =>  '128,38,57,40',
    'e' =>  '38,115,64',
    'f' =>  '64,11,57,38'
);
$line = array();
foreach($ar as $key => $value){
    $line[$key] = explode(',',$value);  
}
$r = 1;
foreach($line as $keyRes => $res){
    $c = 1;
    foreach($line as $keyRes2 => $res2){
        if($c > $r){
            $arMerge[$keyRes][$keyRes2] = array_merge($res,$res2);
        };
        $c++;
    }
    $r++;
}
foreach($arMerge as $intKey1 => $intVal1){
    foreach($intVal1 as $intKey2 => $intVal2){
        foreach($intVal2 as $intVal){
            $resAr[$intKey1][$intKey2][] = (int)$intVal;
        }
    }
}
foreach($resAr as $uniqKey1 => $uniqVal1){
    foreach($uniqVal1 as $uniqKey2 => $uniqVal2){
        if(count(array_unique($uniqVal2)) == 4){
            $result[] = $uniqKey1.'-'.$uniqKey2;    
        }
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Результат выполнения:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a-b
    [1] => a-c
    [2] => a-e
    [3] => a-f
    [4] => b-e
)
```

Теперь вроде правильно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я, наверное, не совсем понятно описал задачу, но в результате нужно получить группы из 4х чисел, именно здесь и требуются навыки комбинаторики. Т.е. из массива всех возможных чисел нужно найти группу из 4-х чисел, которые в одной группе дадут несколько комбинаций. Например мы нашли в числах комбинацию 'b' => '38, 64, 71', но в ней всего 3 числа, до полной группы нужно еще одно число, но не любое, а которое в сочетании с уже найденными числами даст еще комбинацию или несколько. Если добавить 'a' =>  '11, 38', то получится 4 числа, которые в сочетании дают 2 комбинации - b и a

Comment: Получается, что нужно найти или целую группу, в которой встречаются 4 нужных числа, или сгруппировать несколько ячеек, которые дополнят друг друга до 4 чисел? Я Вас правильно понял?

Comment: да верно, именно так, чаще всего нужно будет группировать несколько комбинаций в группу из 4х чисел, т.к. комбинаций из 4х чисел не так много, больше всего комбинаций из 2-х чисел, вот из них и нужно собрать группы, в которых может получится даже 4 комбинации, когда все 4 числа связаны между собой.

Comment: а как поступать в ситуации, если, к примеру, две ячейки дополняют друг друга, но и одно (или несколько но меньше 4) искомых значений повторяются в обеих?

Comment: Не совсем понял ситуацию. 
Допустим, в массиве комбинаций есть такие варианты: 

a => [10, 20], b => [20, 30] c => [30, 40] d=> [40, 10]

из этих комбинаций можно составить группу: [10, 20, 30, 40], которая содержит в себе все 4 комбинации: a, b, c и d

Comment: ааа. так Вам нужно не искать определённые числа, а из предоставленого массива составить комбинации ячеек, используя от 2 до 4 ячеек. А так же количество чисел должно быть равно 4. Теперь я правильно Вас понял?

Comment: Дополнил ответ. старый ответ не удалял, может кому то пригодиться.

Comment: Спасибо большое за код, благодаря вам я теперь нашел нужный алгоритм, это именно то, что мне нужно :)

Answer (score 1):

Если каждому числу из списка комбинаций поставить в соответствие один бит в записи некоторого числа, то комбинации и группы получают свои битовые представления.
При этом:

- Количество ненулевых битов в представлении соответствует количеству чисел в группе или в комбинации (в частности, группе из четырёх чисел соответствует представление с четырьмя ненулевыми битами);
- Перебор всех возможных групп можно осуществить в цикле по представлениям от нуля до 2<sup>k</sup>-1, где к - количество чисел в списке комбинаций;
- Для подсчёта количества ненулевых битов в представлении можно применить [оптимальный 32-битовый алгоритм по Кернигану](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/466515/%D0%AD%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0/469489#469489);
- Проверка принадлежности комбинации группе - это проверка того, что битовое представление комбинации не изменяется при логическом И с битовым представлением группы.

Программа (на оба примера):

```
$combi1 = array (
    "a" => array (11, 38),
    "b" => array (38, 64, 71),
    "c" => array (11, 24, 38, 65),
    "d" => array (128, 38, 57, 40)
);

$combi2 = array(
    'a' =>  array(11,38),
    'b' =>  array(38,64,71),
    'c' =>  array(11,24,38,65),
    'd' =>  array(128,38,57,40),
    'e' =>  array(38,115,64),
    'f' =>  array(64,11,57,38)
);

function bit_count($v){ // подсчёт битов в числе по параллельному методу Кернигана
    $v = $v - (($v >> 1) & 0x55555555);                    // reuse input as temporary
    $v = ($v & 0x33333333) + (($v >> 2) & 0x33333333);     // temp
    $c = (($v + ($v >> 4) & 0xF0F0F0F) * 0x1010101) >> 24; // count
    return $c;
}

function print_bin($arr_bin){ // вывод массива битовых представлений
    $flag_start = 0;
    print("array( ");
    array_walk($arr_bin, function($item, $key) use($flag_start){
        printf("<br>&emsp;'%3s' => %016b", $key, $item);
    });
    print("<br>)<br>");
}

function bit_coding($combi){
    // сливаем и сортируем числа из массивов
    $common = array();
    array_walk($combi, function($item) use(&$common){
        $common = array_unique(array_merge($common, $item));
    });
    sort($common);
    // представляем числа битами, а массивы - комбинациями битов
    $com_bin = array();
    array_walk($combi, function($item, $key) use($common, &$com_bin){
        $item_com_bin = 0;
        array_walk($item, function($val) use($common, &$item_com_bin){
            $item_com_bin |= 1 << array_search($val, $common);  
        });
        $com_bin[$key] = $item_com_bin;
    });
    $bit_combi = array();
    $bit_combi["codes"] = $com_bin;
    $bit_combi["encryptions"] = $common;
    return $bit_combi;
}

function group_from_combs($group_from, $combs, $group_size, $combi_from){
    $all_g = (1 << count($group_from));
    $base_groups = array();
    for($g = 0; $g < $all_g; $g++){ 
        if(bit_count($g) != $group_size) continue;  // оставили группы требуемого размера
        $combi_count = 0;
        array_walk($combs, function($item) use($g,&$combi_count) {
            if ($item == ($item & $g)) $combi_count++;
        });
        if ($combi_count < $combi_from) continue;   // проверили количество комбинаций

        $item_group = array("g"=>$g);       
        array_walk($combs, function($item) use($g, &$item_group) {
            if ($item == ($item & $g))  array_push($item_group, $item);
        });
        array_push($base_groups,$item_group);
    }
    return $base_groups;
}

function decode($n, $decoder){
    $b=0;
    $result = array();
    for($test=$n; $test>0; $test = $test >> 1){
        if($test&1) array_push($result, $decoder[$b]);
        $b++;
    }
    return $result; 
};

print("<br>combi1 = "); var_dump($combi1);
$bit_com1 = bit_coding($combi1);            
print("<br>bit_com1 = "); var_dump($bit_com1);
print("<br>bit_com1[codes] = "); print_bin($bit_com1["codes"]);

$bin_result1 = group_from_combs(
    $bit_com1["encryptions"],   // рассматриваем все возможные группы из чисел, входящих в массив комбинаций
    $bit_com1["codes"],         // проверяем каждую комбинацию на вхождение в группу 
    $group_size = 4,            // количество чисел в группе = 4 
    $combi_from = 2             // количество комбинаций в группе >= 2 
);  
print("<br>bin_result1:");
array_walk($bin_result1, function($item) {
    print("<br>$emsp; "); print_bin($item);
});

$decoder = $bit_com1["encryptions"];
$num_result1=$bin_result1;
array_walk_recursive($num_result1, function(&$item, $key) use($decoder) {
    $item = decode($item, $decoder);
});
print("num_result1 = ");    var_dump($num_result1);

print("<br>combi2 = "); var_dump($combi2);
$bit_com2 = bit_coding($combi2);            
print("<br>bit_com2 = "); var_dump($bit_com2);
print("<br>bit_com2[codes] = "); print_bin($bit_com2["codes"]);

$bin_result2 = group_from_combs(
    $bit_com2["encryptions"],   // рассматриваем все возможные группы из чисел, входящих в массив комбинаций
    $bit_com2["codes"],         // проверяем каждую комбинацию на вхождение в группу 
    $group_size = 4,            // количество чисел в группе = 4 
    $combi_from = 2             // количество комбинаций в группе >= 2 
);  
print("<br>bin_result2:");
array_walk($bin_result2, function($item) {
    print("<br>$emsp; "); print_bin($item);
});

$decoder = $bit_com2["encryptions"];
$num_result2=$bin_result2;
array_walk_recursive($num_result2, function(&$item, $key) use($decoder) {
    $item = decode($item, $decoder);
});
print("num_result2 = ");    var_dump($num_result2);
```

Результаты:

```
combi1 =
array (size=4)
  'a' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 11
      1 => int 38
  'b' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => int 38
      1 => int 64
      2 => int 71
  'c' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => int 11
      1 => int 24
      2 => int 38
      3 => int 65
  'd' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => int 128
      1 => int 38
      2 => int 57
      3 => int 40

bit_com1 =
array (size=2)
  'codes' => 
    array (size=4)
      'a' => int 5
      'b' => int 164
      'c' => int 71
      'd' => int 284
  'encryptions' => 
    array (size=9)
      0 => int 11
      1 => int 24
      2 => int 38
      3 => int 40
      4 => int 57
      5 => int 64
      6 => int 65
      7 => int 71
      8 => int 128

bit_com1[codes] = array( 
 ' a' => 0000000000000101
 ' b' => 0000000010100100
 ' c' => 0000000001000111
 ' d' => 0000000100011100
)

bin_result1:
; array( 
 ' g' => 0000000001000111
 ' 0' => 0000000000000101
 ' 1' => 0000000001000111
)

; array( 
 ' g' => 0000000010100101
 ' 0' => 0000000000000101
 ' 1' => 0000000010100100
)
num_result1 =
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'g' => 
        array (size=4)
          0 => int 11
          1 => int 24
          2 => int 38
          3 => int 65
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 11
          1 => int 38
      1 => 
        array (size=4)
          0 => int 11
          1 => int 24
          2 => int 38
          3 => int 65
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'g' => 
        array (size=4)
          0 => int 11
          1 => int 38
          2 => int 64
          3 => int 71
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 11
          1 => int 38
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => int 38
          1 => int 64
          2 => int 71

combi2 =
array (size=6)
  'a' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 11
      1 => int 38
  'b' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => int 38
      1 => int 64
      2 => int 71
  'c' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => int 11
      1 => int 24
      2 => int 38
      3 => int 65
  'd' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => int 128
      1 => int 38
      2 => int 57
      3 => int 40
  'e' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => int 38
      1 => int 115
      2 => int 64
  'f' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => int 64
      1 => int 11
      2 => int 57
      3 => int 38

bit_com2 =
array (size=2)
  'codes' => 
    array (size=6)
      'a' => int 5
      'b' => int 164
      'c' => int 71
      'd' => int 540
      'e' => int 292
      'f' => int 53
  'encryptions' => 
    array (size=10)
      0 => int 11
      1 => int 24
      2 => int 38
      3 => int 40
      4 => int 57
      5 => int 64
      6 => int 65
      7 => int 71
      8 => int 115
      9 => int 128

bit_com2[codes] = array( 
 ' a' => 0000000000000101
 ' b' => 0000000010100100
 ' c' => 0000000001000111
 ' d' => 0000001000011100
 ' e' => 0000000100100100
 ' f' => 0000000000110101
)

bin_result2:
; array( 
 ' g' => 0000000000110101
 ' 0' => 0000000000000101
 ' 1' => 0000000000110101
)

; array( 
 ' g' => 0000000001000111
 ' 0' => 0000000000000101
 ' 1' => 0000000001000111
)

; array( 
 ' g' => 0000000010100101
 ' 0' => 0000000000000101
 ' 1' => 0000000010100100
)

; array( 
 ' g' => 0000000100100101
 ' 0' => 0000000000000101
 ' 1' => 0000000100100100
)

; array( 
 ' g' => 0000000110100100
 ' 0' => 0000000010100100
 ' 1' => 0000000100100100
)
num_result2 =
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'g' => 
        array (size=4)
          0 => int 11
          1 => int 38
          2 => int 57
          3 => int 64
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 11
          1 => int 38
      1 => 
        array (size=4)
          0 => int 11
          1 => int 38
          2 => int 57
          3 => int 64
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'g' => 
        array (size=4)
          0 => int 11
          1 => int 24
          2 => int 38
          3 => int 65
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 11
          1 => int 38
      1 => 
        array (size=4)
          0 => int 11
          1 => int 24
          2 => int 38
          3 => int 65
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'g' => 
        array (size=4)
          0 => int 11
          1 => int 38
          2 => int 64
          3 => int 71
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 11
          1 => int 38
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => int 38
          1 => int 64
          2 => int 71
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'g' => 
        array (size=4)
          0 => int 11
          1 => int 38
          2 => int 64
          3 => int 115
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 11
          1 => int 38
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => int 38
          1 => int 64
          2 => int 115
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      'g' => 
        array (size=4)
          0 => int 38
          1 => int 64
          2 => int 71
          3 => int 115
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => int 38
          1 => int 64
          2 => int 71
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => int 38
          1 => int 64
          2 => int 115
```