# Эффективнейшие методы для нахождения единиц в двоичном виде числа

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Дано число в двоичной системе исчисления, например 10011010.
Какие есть эффективные методы узнать количество битов в этом числе, в которых значение равно TRUE?

Я придумал только два:

1. Число & 1 и если равно 1, то увеличивать счетчик, а потом число сдвигать на один в право.
2. Создать lookup table в котором индех - это числа от 0 до 255, а значение это кол-во едениц в этом числе.

Какие еще есть методы?

Comment: Ключевые слова: [`popcount()`](http://wm.ite.pl/articles/sse-popcount.html), [вес Хэмминга.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight)

Comment: "...в которых значение равно TRUE"??? Что такое `TRUE` и к чему оно тут?

Comment: Бит, значение которого равно единице, TRUE, HIGH - как пожелаете! :)

Comment: [std::popcount](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/popcount)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Самый эффективный метод следующий: пока число (его надо интерпретировать как беззнаковое число, чтобы подсчитать все единицы), допустим `n`, не равно нулю выполнить следующую операцию

```
n &= n - 1;
```

и соответственно увеличить счетчик единиц на единицу.

Принцип следующий. Допустим в числе имеется одна 1

```
0b00100000
```

Если из этого числа вычесть 1, то получится

```
0b00011111
```

Теперь если применить бинарную операцию И, то получим

```
0b00100000
&
0b00011111
==========
0b00000000
```

Число стало равным 0, следовательно оно содержало только одну 1, так как данная операция была проделана только один раз.

Используя же те методы, которые вы указали, то придется сдвигать либо само число, либо единицу 6 раз, чтобы добраться до единицы в исходном числе, и 6 раз придется выполнить сравнение с единицей. А таблица просмотра совершенно не применима для чисел, которые занимают более одного байта. Тем более она еще занимает место в памяти для такой простой задачи.

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо!!
А какие еще есть способы?

Comment: @MichaelVaysman Наверное есть еще способы, но мне представляется, что данный способ - один из самых лаконичных.

Comment: Я понял. Спасибо Вам большое!

Answer (score 11):

Ознакомился со статьёй по ссылке от VladD.
Оптимальный метод для 32-разрядного слова содержит 3 строчки суммарно на 12 операций:

```
v = v - ((v >> 1) & 0x55555555);                    // reuse input as temporary
v = (v & 0x33333333) + ((v >> 2) & 0x33333333);     // temp
c = ((v + (v >> 4) & 0xF0F0F0F) * 0x1010101) >> 24; // count
```

Данные большей разрядности проще разбить на такие слова, поскольку дальнейшее алгоритмическое продвижение нивелируется реальной структурой физических устройств и типов данных в языках программирования.

P.S. (17.11.2017)
Если речь идёт о младших 32 разрядах слова большей разрядности, то ранее приведённый алгоритм требует дополнительной очистки верхних разрядов `с &= 0x3F`.

Стал актуальным алгоритм для 64-битного слова (3 строчки, 12 операций):

```
v = v - ((v >> 1) & 0x5555555555555555);                        // sums in pairs of bits, g+l=(2g+l)-l  
v = (v & 0x3333333333333333) + ((v >> 2) & 0x3333333333333333); // sums in tetrades
c = (((v + (v >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F) * 0x101010101010101) >> 56; // total sum
```

Алгоритм собирает сумму по методу двоичного слияния.
При сложении чётных и нечётных битов использовано тождество: g+l = (2g+l)-l.
При слиянии побайтовых сумм значимы только 7 младших разрядов, и верхние разряды обрезаются один раз.

Кстати: при использовании масок можно подсчитать сумму любых битов 64-разрядного слова.

Comment: Кстати, возможно, вас заинтересует, что делает компилятор с кодом: https://godbolt.org/g/gcB23x. (Об этом недавно была [статья на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/339962/).)

Comment: @VladD неплохо). И актуально: примерно неделя, как я возвращаюсь к ANSI C (создаю сервисные библиотеки и перевожу свои наработки с PHP).

Answer (score 11):

Раз уж пошла речь об ассемблере, в Intel'овских процессорах, поддерживающий SSE4, есть [инструкция POPCNT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4#POPCNT_and_LZCNT) (в 16-, 32- и 64-разрядном вариантах), которая прямо считает количество единичных бит. Этот вариант упомянут в статье, на которую сослался @jfs в комментариях к вопросу.

---

Эта инструкция не доступна прямо в языке, но доступна в популярных компиляторах как интринсик (функция-расширение, специфическая для компилятора):

- `__builtin_popcount`, `__builtin_popcountl`, `__builtin_popcountll` [в gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) (спасибо @avp за наводку),
- `__popcnt16`, `__popcnt`, `__popcnt64` [в MSVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385231.aspx),
- clang поддерживает [те же имена](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/popcntintrin_8h_source.html), что и у gcc.

Comment: Погуглил `gcc builtin popcount` и нашел в https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html `int __builtin_popcount (unsigned int x)` (и др.)

Comment: У MSVC [тоже есть](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385231.aspx), как оказалось.

Answer (score 6):

Кроме классического Кернигановского способа, приведённого @Vlad from Moscow, есть ещё несколько. Почитайте [здесь](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive). (И гуглится по запросу «bit hacks».)

Например, можно разложить число на байты, как вы и предлагали, или тетрады, и для каждого байта/тетрады подсчитать сумму заранее. Но это, мне кажется, не будет эффективнее.