# Использование битовых флагов

Tags: c++

Пишу класс корабль для игры морской бой. Хочу сделать переменную, в которой буду хранить данные о битых палубах. Мне кажется, для этого идеально подошел бы битовый флаг - DECK_1 & DECK_2 & DECK_3 & DECK_4.

Как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Взять и реализовать. Поскольку палуб не больше 8 - unsigned char хватит.

Comment: Я не знаю, как это написать :(

Comment: @T2skler google "C set bit" + google "С reset bit"

Comment: Почему битовые флаги? У вас **очень** жёсткие требования к занимаемой памяти? Если нет, не морочьте себе голову и используйте флаг в каждом из полей.

Comment: У меня нет полей, просто класс Ship у которого есть enum содержащий количество палуб (1-4)

Comment: @T2skler Вопрос не понятен. Что именно вы не можете реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напишите перечисление, допустим, следующим образом

```
enum Decks 
{
    DECK_0 = 0, 
    DECK_1 = 1, 
    DECK_2 = DECK_1 << 1, 
    DECK_3 = DECK_2 << 1, 
    DECK_4 = DECK_3 << 1 
    ALL_DECKS = DECK_1 | DECK_2 | DECK_3 | DECK_4 
};


Decks alive = DECK_0;

//   Подбита палуба 2

alive |= DECK_2;

//  Подбита палуба 2?

if ( ( alive & DECK_2 ) == DECK_2 ) { /* палуба 2 подбита */ }

// Подбиты все палубы?

if ( alive ==  ALL_DECKS ) { /* все палубы подбиты */ }
```

Comment: @T2skler Смотрите мой дополненный ответ.

Comment: То, что нужно, очень просто и красиво. Спасибо

Comment: @T2skler Только проверка `alive ==  ALL_DECKS` проверит что именно 4 палубы подбиты. А если у вас трехпалубник то надо по другому, а если двухпалубник то опять другая проверка. Хотя с другой стороны можно для двухпалубника сразу ставить 2 палубы подбитые из 4х и ждать попаданий в оставшиеся

Comment: @Mike Можно дополнить перечисление дополнительными значениями для однопалубных, двухпалубных и т.д. либо ввести  отдельное перечисление для типов кораблей.

Comment: alive |= DECK_2; не проходит, надо alive = alive | DECK_2;

Comment: @DECK_1 Возможно. Я не проверял, так как нет под рукой компилятора. Если такая проблема имеется, то она связана с необходимостью явного указания преобразования выражение в перечисление.

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned char flag;    // 8 бит

int deck=2;            // Номер палубы с которым работаем, нумерация с нуля !!!

flag |= 1 << deck;     // Установка бита, метим палубу подбитой
flag &= ~(1 << deck);  // Сбрасываем бит (палуба починилась :) )
if(flag & (1 << deck)) // проверка установлен ли бит
 {
  //бит установлен
 }
```

Определение количества подбитых палуб ([по алгоритму Vald from Moscow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/466515/%D0%AD%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0/466523#466523))

```
int count=0;
for(int tmp=flag;tmp;count++) tmp &= tmp - 1;
// Все, в count количество подбитых палуб
```

Comment: Жесть, я думал все проще

Comment: Ну не знаю, не вижу вроде никакой жести. ИЛИ (`|`) устанавливает, И `&` сбрасывать может. остается только биты написать. Если маска битовая заранее известна то можно же и проще `flag|=5` установит 0й и 2й биты (5=0b0101)

Comment: Жесть в том, что не надо усложнять себе жизнь. Для большего удобства можно использовать `std::bitset` или `std::vector<bool>`.